# About : Tiring of you

Tags: phrase-usage

> ‎It is tiring of you to ask me again and again about what you have already solved!

I wrote the sentence myself.

What I want to convey is that the trait of you to ask me again and again about what you have already solved tires me.

I want to know whether Tiring of you is acceptable or not, and if not natural, would you please suggest a more natural sentence, and explain which point makes the sentence unnatural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *find it tiring* to be asked again and again for .... {something}.

It is *tiring* to be asked over and over for ... {something}.

The person being asked is the one who is getting tired, that is, the one who is **tiring** (intransitive verb).  The  repetitive questioning is **tiresome**.

**to tire** is also transitive. To tire someone...

You are tiring me with your questions.

But the quality of being tiring to others is expressed by the adjective **tiresome**.